# How do I set-up XCTest unit testing with a Cocos2d-v3 / SpriteBuilder project?

Tags: unit-testing, cocos2d-iphone, xctest, spritebuilder

I am using the new SpriteBuilder (was Cocosbuilder) and Cocos2d-v3 to build an interactive book. It is my normal practice to code using unit tests and I want this project to incorporate XCTest.

So far I have gone to the test navigator in Xcode, hit the '+' at the bottom and added a test target per Apple's documentation. Xcode then created a test target and a sample test class (just a .m file with a failing unit test).

I commented out the textExample, and hit Command+U to test - and it failed to compile...monumentally. Bazillions of errors and warnings.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: You don't really need cocos2d as you can't unit test most of cocos2d ( ie no actions, nothing visual or timing related, no user input). If you design the model of your app well it will not have dependencies on cocos2d. Thus the real unit test for your code (algorithms and data) is to make it testable without requiring cocos2d.

Comment: Thanks - I did see some of your advice as I was considering whether to unit test at all. I would love to isolate a bit more but my limited knowledge of the build/compile process forced me to pull all the cocos, chipmunk, and spritebuilder files in - not that I want to unit test all that previously unit tested work, just couldn't avoid it. Any thoughts on avoiding that mess? I'm anxiously awaiting your Kobold integration with SpriteBuilder - will that facilitate unit testing of my logic/model classes?